# Meu código VHDL não compila nunca

Tags: vhdl

Eu fiz um algoritmo em vhdl e meu programa não tá compilando, ele tá demorando em média de 30 minutos até uma hora e fica travado nos 80%, eu não sei porque, eu to usando a versão do quartus 13.01, e a minha máquina não é ruim eu tenho um intel core i7-5500U com 8GB de ram, tentei fazer alguns métodos para acelerar um pouco o processo de compilação mas continua travando na mesma percentagem, eu não sei se é porque meu código não está muito bem construído, até porque não manjo muito de vhdl, se alguém puder me ajudar eu agradeceria.

OBS.: o meu código é bem simples pra falar a verdade, eu preciso pegar uma entrada de um número de 8bits, e retornar o maior numero primo dentro do intervalo da entrada(por exemplo se a entrada é 10, eu preciso retornar o maior primo dentro do intervalo de 1 até 10), consegui fazer um código parecido em python, não entendo porque não estou conseguindo fazer/compilar ele em vhdl.

Meu código vhdl:

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity maior_primo is port(
  n : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
  s : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
 );
end maior_primo;

architecture Behavioral of maior_primo is
    signal maxtx : integer;
   signal k : natural := 1;

    function maiorpri(limit : natural) return integer is
      variable c : natural;
      variable l : natural := 1;
      variable max : integer;
      constant m : natural := limit;
    begin
      for i in 1 to 10 loop
        c := 0;
        for j in 1 to 10 loop
            if (k mod l) = 0 then
                c := c + 1;
            elsif c = 2 then
                max := k;
                exit;
            end if;
            l := l+1;
            exit when j = m;
        end loop;
        k <= k+1;
        exit when i = m;
      end loop;

      return max;
    end function;
begin
process(n)
begin
   maxtx <= to_integer(unsigned(n));
   s <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(maiorpri(maxtx),s'length));
end process;

end Behavioral;
```

Comment: VHDL não é compilável, mas sim sintetizável. 
Se tu tá rodando a síntese, ela pode demorar bastante sim. No case desse código, a síntese não vai funcionar pois tu está usando funções não sintetizáveis em hardware (por exemplo esse for loop).

O software não tá gerando nenhuma mensagem de erro?

Comment: Não, mas descobri isso que você falou depois de vários testes, parece que o vhdl não consegue sintetizar loops sobre loops, então tive que dividir essa função em duas e sintetizou e funcionou normal, no caso fiz um identificador de primos em uma function e coloquei maior primo em outra function.